# How to use std::regex to find the next match in a string?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

Trying to use `std::regex` in a scanner. So all it is supposed to do in my case is to find the first match starting at `const char *p` of the input sequence. It is not supposed to skip anything. It just needs to match as long as the expression is valid. Then return what it got.

Is that possible?

Here my humble attempt:

```
#include <regex>

static void Test()
{
    const char *numbers = "500 42 399 4711";
    std::regex expr("[0-9]+");
    std::match_results<const char *> matches;
    if (std::regex_match
            (&numbers[0]
            ,&numbers[strlen(numbers)]
            , matches
            , expr
            , std::regex_constants::match_continuous))
    {
        printf("match: %s\n", matches[0]);
    }
    else 
        puts("No match.");
}
```

What I am looking for is that it only returns `"500"` as a successful match. But I cannot even get it to return true...

In contrast, were the input `"    500"` it should return false.

`std::regex_search()` also does not seem to do what I want. It tries to find EVERY match, not just the first match.

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely need `regex_search`. And `printf("match: %s\n", matches[0]);` is quite wrong.

Comment: If only I ever got there ;)

Comment: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Comment: The ``[0-9]+`` is okay. It is about the handling of those new regex classes. They seem to hide my use case pretty well. There is also some regex_iterator but it also seems to look at all the input instead of stoping after 1 match. (expensive)

Comment: Why do you think `regex_search` tries to find every match? It doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
`regex_match` to `regex_search`.  The second argument is redundant:

```
if (std::regex_search
        (numbers
        , matches
        , expr
        , std::regex_constants::match_continuous)) { ... }
```

Also `matches [0]` is not a c-string, and instead is a `std:: sub_match <char const *> const`.  You cannot pass it to `printf` without writing something like:

```
printf ("match: %s", matches[0].str ().c_str ());
```

It is overloaded for streams, though, so you can instead
`std:: cout << matches [0]`.

See it run:
https://ideone.com/ChqQIb

Comment: With /that/ documentation I would have expected matches to contain all matches, not just one... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This must be doing with std::regex_iterator, see for details(example included) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator

Comment: While it is OK for an answer to refer to an external page for a deeper explanation the answer itself should at least contain a basic solution.